# UIButtons display differently on UIImageView when created at design time vs. run time

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have added some `UIButton` objects into .xib file, and some `UIButton` objects with the code.

But now I am facing one problem. While Zooming the UIImageView the UIButtons that are added through code are shown on the UIImageView and those that are added with .xib file are below the UIImageView.

Code for UIButton added with code:

```
btnBrightness = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
btnBrightness.Frame = new RectangleF (540, 20, 95, 37);
btnBrightness.SetTitle ("Brightness", UIControlState.Normal);
```

More details: 
[monotouch](http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/UIButton-Problem-td4550977.html)

Comment: It is but obvious problem of yours...because you are passing STATIC values to button-frame while creating....you have to set values accordingly..:)

Comment: I try to set the values as you told but its not work

Comment: You must have added the buttons before you added the UIIMageView in xib. you should add the buttons after you add image view.

Comment: thanks for help issues is solve I just add line of code in ViewDidLoad() which is this.Add(UIImageView)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solve I just add line of code in ViewDidLoad() which is

`this.Add(UIImageView)`

Using this line Its work as I want.

OR

create a container view for all your buttons and add the buttons to this

mainView.InsertSubview(buttonContainerView,mainView.Subviews.Count);